# Set language of Wikipedia article on mobile page

Tags: wikipedia, mobile

I want to change the language of a Wikipedia article, as you would do on the left navigation bar in desktop view.

Unfortunately I can't find the functionality on mobile view without switching to desktop view.

Is this just too hard to find or is this not present in mobile view?

Comment: You're using the mobile web site and not the app, right?

Comment: Correct it is the mobile website.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's certainly non-obvious.

Under the title of the article, if there are other languages available, is an icon that looks like a kanji letter and the letter "A".

[image: icon for selecting language]

Tap that and it will offer the other languages available for that article.

[image: select new language for 'Bear']